# Date Field Filter and Date fields inside of Grid

Tags: solspace, grid, date-field-filter

I am using Solspace's Date Field Filter to group sales on a site. I have the date coming in like I need it, but I am not receiving filtered results...

Is there something different I need to do in order to use the date fields from a grid field? Or is Grid usage not allowed?

I verified the dates by rendering them out. Since it didn't work, I even tried to use [Stash][3] to pass that into the channel entries tag. Still no good. Is there something I am doing wrong [Solspace](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/884/solspace)? My date field is in a grid like this:

Grid Field = `{sale_dates_and_times}`

Sub Fields = date | opening_time | closing_time 
or

`{sale_dates_and_times:date}` `{sale_dates_and_times:opening_time}` `{sale_dates_and_times:closing_time}`

I have this now:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    date_field="{sale_dates_and_times:date}"
    date_field_start="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %A'}"
    channel='sale'
    limit='5'
    orderby="{sale_dates_and_times:date}"
    sort="asc"
    paginate="bottom"
    dynamic="no"
}
```

In my test I should just see 1 entry since there is one set to a previous date range, one set to current date ranges, and one set for a future date range. However, I am getting all entries returned.

These are with the following dates:

Entry-1:

```
Friday 10-01-2015 — 9:00am-9:00am
Saturday 10-02-2015 — 9:00am-9:00am
Sunday 10-03-2015 — 8:00am-8:00am
```

Entry-2:

```
Tuesday 08-01-2015 — 9:00am-9:00am
Wednesday 08-02-2015 — 9:00am-9:00am
Thursday 08-03-2015 — 8:00am-8:00am
```

Entry-3:

```
Friday 12-25-2015 — 9:00am-9:00am
Saturday 12-26-2015 — 9:00am-9:00am
Sunday 129-27-2015 — 8:00am-8:00am
```

Why would all three be rendering in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this the same question as here?: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/33992/whats-the-best-way-to-get-yesterdays-date

Comment: It is the same as the updated question. Since the original question was different than what the updated question was and you had already answered the original question, I thought it best to start a new question. Sorry if this was not the proper way.  ;)